# How to deploy a typescript-based cloud function with terraform

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I've got a cloud function written with Typescript, I can't get it to successfully deploy as for some reason, it's completely ignoring all dependencies and can't load modules, even the `@google-cloud/functions-framework` module itself.

I'm using Gen2 cloud-functions and archiving the source folder for deployment. Using cloud build for building.

I've tried everything I can think of, literally.